# Mass conservation in fluid dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, mass, conservation-laws, flow

I am trying to derive the mass conservation equation:

> [image: Blockquote]

In one of the step we are given the equation to find Fluid mass gained through a small element of the surface  in a time  is:

> [image: Blockquote]

I don't understand how the equation is got.

Here is diagram i was given

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mass is equal to density times volume, in your case:
$$ dM = \rho \cdot dV. $$

To compute $dV$, you need the volume of a parallelogram with base area $dS$ and (perpendicular) height $h$ so that $dV = dS \cdot h$. Your base area is $dS = dA$ in your sketch, and the height $h$ is the distance travelled *perpendicular* to $dS$. 
 Since $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ is by definition normal to $dS$, the height is just the projcection of the total distance travelled $\ell$ onto this axis, so $h = \boldsymbol{\ell}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}$. 
 What is $\ell$? Distance is equal to velocity times time: $\ell = \mathbf{u}\cdot dt$.

The minus sign is probably because mass is flowing *out* of your surface and hence it's a loss.

Putting it all together:

$dM = -\rho \cdot dV = -\rho\, \mathbf{u}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}\,dS\, dt$

Answer (score 0):

The given  equation
$$dm=-\rho\ \mathbf{u}\cdot\hat{n}\  dSdt$$
or $$\frac{dm}{dt}=-\rho \ \mathbf{u}\cdot\hat{n}\  dS$$
On the left-hand side, You have a rate at which the mass is changing in the given volume. On the right-hand side, You have the mass flux that goes out of the volume in time $dt$ multiplied with density. That way it makes sense.

---

Now How to derive this:

Note that $\hat{n}$ is a unit vector perpendicular to the surface. We emphasize that $\mathbf{u}$ is the velocity of a fluid at a given point $(x,y,z)$ in space and at a given time $t$. The mass of fluid flowing in unit time through an element $d\mathbf{S}$ of the surface bounding this volume is $\rho \mathbf{u}\cdot d\mathbf{S}$; the magnitude of the vector $d\mathbf{S}$ is equal to the area of the surface element, and its direction is along normal.
$$\rho \mathbf{u}\cdot d\mathbf{S}=\rho \mathbf{u}\cdot \hat{n}dS$$
For time dt this would give the above relation
$$dm=\rho \mathbf{u}\cdot d\mathbf{S} dt$$
The vector  $$\mathbf{j}=\rho \mathbf{u}$$
is called the *mass flux density.*